# Group-wise-max - hierarchical data query help

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, groupwise

the first part of this problem was solved by some good help on here yesterday, but I've been struggling today to complete the query I need. I am trying to pull multiple columns from 5 joined tables based on some conditions, but I want the result set to contain only one distinct "data entry" per p.id (the pet id which is a foreign key in the data entry table) - this data_entry should have the highest number of all the data_entries with that p.id (i.e a specific pet could have data_entries numbered 1,2 and 3 - I only want number 3). I have the code below working correctly in the first query, but I want to add an additional clause which checks the "updated" date of the max record returned, but I can't seem to work out how to integrate this clause correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated:

This simplified query works correctly across 3 joined tables (without the date comparison clause)

```
SELECT `p`.`id`, `o`.`id`, `o`.`email`, MAX(d.number) 
FROM (`pets` AS `p`, `owners` AS `o`, `data_entries` AS `d`) 
WHERE `p`.`owner_id` = `o`.`id` 
AND `p`.`id` = `d`.`pet_id` 
GROUP BY `p`.`id`, `o`.`id`, `o`.`email` 
ORDER BY `d`.`number` DESC
```

However, when i try to add the date comparison clause below and the joins between the extra tables, the query doesn't perform the date comparison against the "updated" column of the data_entry with the MAX number, instead it checks against the the lowest number.

```
SELECT `p`.`id` AS `pet_id`, `o`.`id` AS `owner_id`, `o`.`email`, MAX(d.number) 
FROM (`pets` AS `p`, `owners` AS `o`, `data_entries` AS `d`, `k_records_owners` AS `kcro`, `k_records` AS `kcr`) 
WHERE `p`.`owner_id` = `o`.`id` 
AND `p`.`id` = `d`.`pet_id` 
AND `p`.`kc_number` = `kcr`.`do_dg_dog_no` 
AND `kcr`.`pa_breeder_no` = `kcro`.`contact_no` 
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(`d`.`updated`, "%Y-%m-%d") <= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 day), "%Y-%m-%d") 
GROUP BY `p`.`id`, `o`.`id`, `o`.`email` 
ORDER BY MAX(d.number) DESC
```

EDIT: latest attempt - results in Unknown column 'd2.updated' in 'having clause'

```
SELECT p.id AS pet_id, o.id AS owner_id, o.email, MAX(d.number) as max_d, d.updated 
FROM (pets AS p, owners AS o, data_entries AS d, data_entries AS d2, kennel_club_records_owners AS kcro, kennel_club_records AS kcr)
WHERE p.owner_id = o.id 
AND p.id = d.pet_id 
AND p.kc_number = kcr.do_dg_dog_no 
AND kcr.pa_breeder_no = kcro.contact_no 
AND d.number = d2.number
GROUP BY p.id, o.id, o.email 
having FROM_UNIXTIME(d2.updated, '%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 day), '%Y-%m-%d') 
ORDER BY max_d DESC
```

Comment: Use single quotes, not double: `AND FROM_UNIXTIME(d.updated, '%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 day), '%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT p.id AS pet_id, o.id AS owner_id, o.email, MAX(d.number) as max_d, d.updated 
FROM (pets AS p, owners AS o, data_entries AS d, data_entries AS d2, kennel_club_records_owners AS kcro, kennel_club_records AS kcr)
WHERE p.owner_id = o.id 
AND p.id = d.pet_id 
AND p.kc_number = kcr.do_dg_dog_no 
AND kcr.pa_breeder_no = kcro.contact_no 
AND d2.number = max_d
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(d2.updated, '%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 day), '%Y-%m-%d') 
GROUP BY p.id, o.id, o.email 
ORDER BY max_d DESC
```

Comment: hi ovais - i tried that, but the HAVING date comparison isn't comparing against the d.updated field of the latest (MAX d.number) data_entry - the query works correctly apart from this one crucial clause, which is where i'm stuck. Any other ideas?

Comment: introduce another join with the data_entires table as follows

FROM (pets AS p, owners AS o, data_entries AS d, data_entries AS d2, k_records_owners AS kcro, k_records AS kcr) 

and then in the where clause

d.number = d2.number

and then in the having clause relace d.updated with d2.updated

Comment: Now results in Unknown column 'd2.updated' in 'having clause' - I've edited my original post so you can see the exact query which is causing that error (thanks for the help so far)

Comment: i have edited the query, actually it was my mistake, having should only be used in columns present in group by clause or columns that are being used in aggregate functions. Anyways i have moved the date checking from having to where. Hope it works

Comment: the date check is still not being done with the max data entry number - I know there are a few pets with data_entries numbered 1, 2 and 3 - these shouldn't appear in the result set as data entry number 3 is within the time period being checked, but because the comparison is done against the date of data entry number 1, these are showing up in the results. Hope that makes sense

Comment: i understand what you are saying, i have edited the query, i hope it works now